# Is there a better way to write this, or a shorter more compact way

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, for-loop, raphael

I am creating a path with jsfiddle that is looped a certain number of times based on the a number input from the user. eg.,the user types in any number less than 30 1 path(a bottle) will draw on the paper the user types in any number above 30 2 paths(2 bottles) will draw on the paper. Eventually I want to have it continue up to 10 paths(10 bottles) so the ranges would be (0-30,31-60,61-90...) Currently it is working, but if I write out the whole thing, it will be alot of code, and before I do so, I was wondering if anyone new a way of shortening this down. I'm sure there is a way I just can't figure it out.

http://jsfiddle.net/anderskitson/Gqbmk/

```
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById("notepad"), 500, 500);

$("input").keyup(function() {
            var value = parseInt($(this).val());
            paper.clear();
    if (value > 30) {
                for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

               var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*200 +25);
               var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*200 +25);
               var randomNumber3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*25);
               var path_a = paper.path("M242.07,270.119c0,0-14.596-30.606-7.625-35.793 c3.864-2.876,2.145-18.561,1.832-18.784c-0.313-0.224-1.839-0.319-1.839-0.319c-1.555-0.192-0.201-3.456-0.201-3.456 s0,0-0.598-0.352c-0.598-0.351,1.129-1.345,1.129-1.345c3.738-2.785,10.449-2.983,11.126-2.344c0.677,0.64-0.354,1.44-0.354,1.44 s0.73,0.832,1.333,2.111c0.604,1.28-0.792,1.665-0.792,1.665c1.852,6.718,9.877,14.935,9.877,14.935 c4.795,0.589,7.7,10.683,7.7,10.683l6.271,22.746C269.929,261.307,263.641,270.119,242.07,270.119z");
               path_a.attr({fill: 'none',stroke: '#231F20',"stroke-width": '3',"stroke-miterlimit": '10','stroke-opacity': '1'}).data('id', 'path_a');
               path_a.translate(i*30, 10);
               path_a.rotate(randomNumber3);

            }//end of for statement
    }else{


            for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

               var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*200 +25);
               var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*200 +25);
               var randomNumber3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*25);
               var path_a = paper.path("M242.07,270.119c0,0-14.596-30.606-7.625-35.793 c3.864-2.876,2.145-18.561,1.832-18.784c-0.313-0.224-1.839-0.319-1.839-0.319c-1.555-0.192-0.201-3.456-0.201-3.456 s0,0-0.598-0.352c-0.598-0.351,1.129-1.345,1.129-1.345c3.738-2.785,10.449-2.983,11.126-2.344c0.677,0.64-0.354,1.44-0.354,1.44 s0.73,0.832,1.333,2.111c0.604,1.28-0.792,1.665-0.792,1.665c1.852,6.718,9.877,14.935,9.877,14.935 c4.795,0.589,7.7,10.683,7.7,10.683l6.271,22.746C269.929,261.307,263.641,270.119,242.07,270.119z");
               path_a.attr({fill: 'none',stroke: '#231F20',"stroke-width": '3',"stroke-miterlimit": '10','stroke-opacity': '1'}).data('id', 'path_a');
               path_a.translate(i*30, 10);
               path_a.rotate(randomNumber3);

            }//end of for statement

}//end of else statement
```

});

Comment: This sounds like a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MikeSamuel it sort of *sounds* like one but IMO it's too trivial for CR. I'd rather see it asked and answered here, personally.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not display a minimal understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the redundant code into a separate function.

Also, `randomNumber1` and `randomNumber2` were unused.

```
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById("notepad"), 500, 500);

function drawBottles(count) {
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {

       var randomNumber3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*25);
       var path_a = paper.path("M242.07,270.119c0,0-14.596-30.606-7.625-35.793 c3.864-2.876,2.145-18.561,1.832-18.784c-0.313-0.224-1.839-0.319-1.839-0.319c-1.555-0.192-0.201-3.456-0.201-3.456 s0,0-0.598-0.352c-0.598-0.351,1.129-1.345,1.129-1.345c3.738-2.785,10.449-2.983,11.126-2.344c0.677,0.64-0.354,1.44-0.354,1.44 s0.73,0.832,1.333,2.111c0.604,1.28-0.792,1.665-0.792,1.665c1.852,6.718,9.877,14.935,9.877,14.935 c4.795,0.589,7.7,10.683,7.7,10.683l6.271,22.746C269.929,261.307,263.641,270.119,242.07,270.119z");
       path_a.attr({fill: 'none',stroke: '#231F20',"stroke-width": '3',"stroke-miterlimit": '10','stroke-opacity': '1'}).data('id', 'path_a');
       path_a.translate(i*30, 10);
       path_a.rotate(randomNumber3);

    }//end of for statement
}

$("input").keyup(function() {
    var value = parseInt($(this).val());
    paper.clear();
    if (value > 30) {
        drawBottles(2);
    } else {
        drawBottles(1);
    }//end of else statement
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gqbmk/2/

Comment: This works for me except that when the input field is blank, or deleted to blank paper.clear isn't ran like it was before.

Comment: @AndersKitson it doesn't seem to clear the paper in your original fiddle either. I didn't change that part.

Comment: oh your right, that's the last piece to my puzzle any suggestion for getting that to work.

Comment: @AndersKitson unfortunately I have very little experience with canvas... The only advice I can give is to open a separate question about that. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Both for loops look the same. If the end point in the loop is the only diff then set that as a variable and only write the for loop 1 time.

```
    $("input").keyup(function() {
                var value = parseInt($(this).val());
                paper.clear();
       var endVal = value > 30 ? 2 : 1; //all values that change between the two define as such
       for (i = 0; i < endVal; i++) {
          var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*200 +25);
          var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*200 +25);
          var randomNumber3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*25);
          var path_a = paper.path("M242.07,270.119c0,0-14.596-30.606-7.625-35.793 c3.864-2.876,2.145-18.561,1.832-18.784c-0.313-0.224-1.839-0.319-1.839-0.319c-1.555-0.192-0.201-3.456-0.201-3.456 s0,0-0.598-0.352c-0.598-0.351,1.129-1.345,1.129-1.345c3.738-2.785,10.449-2.983,11.126-2.344c0.677,0.64-0.354,1.44-0.354,1.44 s0.73,0.832,1.333,2.111c0.604,1.28-0.792,1.665-0.792,1.665c1.852,6.718,9.877,14.935,9.877,14.935 c4.795,0.589,7.7,10.683,7.7,10.683l6.271,22.746C269.929,261.307,263.641,270.119,242.07,270.119z");
                   path_a.attr({fill: 'none',stroke: '#231F20',"stroke-width": '3',"stroke-miterlimit": '10','stroke-opacity': '1'}).data('id', 'path_a');
                   path_a.translate(i*30, 10);
                   path_a.rotate(randomNumber3);

      }//end of for statement
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Mod of GGG's code. Enabling you to keep running in steps of 30

```
var stepping = 30;
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById("notepad"), 500, 500);

function drawBottles (count) {
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {

       var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*200 +25);
       var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*200 +25);
       var randomNumber3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*25);
       var path_a = paper.path("M242.07,270.119c0,0-14.596-30.606-7.625-35.793 c3.864-2.876,2.145-18.561,1.832-18.784c-0.313-0.224-1.839-0.319-1.839-0.319c-1.555-0.192-0.201-3.456-0.201-3.456 s0,0-0.598-0.352c-0.598-0.351,1.129-1.345,1.129-1.345c3.738-2.785,10.449-2.983,11.126-2.344c0.677,0.64-0.354,1.44-0.354,1.44 s0.73,0.832,1.333,2.111c0.604,1.28-0.792,1.665-0.792,1.665c1.852,6.718,9.877,14.935,9.877,14.935 c4.795,0.589,7.7,10.683,7.7,10.683l6.271,22.746C269.929,261.307,263.641,270.119,242.07,270.119z");
       path_a.attr({fill: 'none',stroke: '#231F20',"stroke-width": '3',"stroke-miterlimit": '10','stroke-opacity': '1'}).data('id', 'path_a');
       path_a.translate(i*30, 10);
       path_a.rotate(randomNumber3);

    }//end of for statement
}

$("input").keyup(function() {
    var value = parseInt($(this).val());
    paper.clear();

    drawBottles(Math.floor(value/stepping));

});​
```

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that part. Might as well cap it at ten bottles while you're at it ;)

Comment: There is one thing I am still trying to get. I want there to be one bottle when a number under 30 is inputted, but right now 0 are shown.

Comment: Sorry, just a little bug. You want this: `drawBottles(Math.floor(value/stepping) + 1);`